# Array of dict pList returns only indices of Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, plist

I have a plist that looks like this with a count of 81 "dictionary" items:

[image: plist array of 81 dictionary items]

I have this code which reads pList into newArray

```
NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DukeCruiseControlTable" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

When I look at newArray in the debugger I get:

[image: newArray holds just indices]

newArray has the right number of elements, so it is reading the right file.  But instead of containing the content of each element it is showing just the index of the element (e.g. [3]).

What am I doing wrong?

Being new to iOS I thought perhaps the debugger just showed me the indices of an Array, but when I use the next code to read the array into another array of objects I get an error that indicates that the newArray element is "[3]" or whatever the index is.

```
for (dukeperfPerfChartLine *object in newArray)
{
    [self.perfTable addObject:object];
}
```

Comment: Paste the error log. I don't think there are error with the array. the `object` is an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: To debug you might also add a breakpoint and print the description of array at a particular index.

Comment: Is `dukeperfPerfChartLine` a subclass of `NSDictionary`? If so, I would recommend trying to get an actual value out of the plist instead of just debugging or copying the array. Try something like `int value = [[[newArray objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"expTAS_plus20"] intValue]; NSLog(@"%d",value);`

Comment: @Isaac It is extremely unlikely that `NSDictionary` is subclassed, doing so requires several methods be be over-ridden.

Comment: @Zaph I ask because OP mentions that he is getting an error with the for loop at the end of his post. His array holds `NSDictionary` objects, yet he enumerates them as `dukeperfPerfChartLine`. I was unsure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any problem in reading the file, in debugger it will show only the indices, you can try printing the newArray just after reading from the file as:

NSLog(@"%@",newArray);

For reading the dictionaries from the **newArray**,I think you should try this:

**EDITED**:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in newArray)
{
    NSArray *allKeys = [dict allKeys];
    for (NSString *key in allKeys)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@=%@",key,[dict objectForKey:key]); 
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: This answered the main question.  Debug ONLY shows the indices.  The for loop is still a problem -- but that is likely because values are coming in from the plist as numbers and dukeperfPerfChartLine uses NSDecimalNumbers.  I don't know how to solve it (suggestions appreciated), but at least now I am focused on the right problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat I have modified my answer to give clear idea about how you can access the NSNumber elements from the **newArray**.

Answer (score 0):

A comment to the answer by @Rajeev but as an answer just for the formatting.

Two other methods using different enumeration methods:

Using fast enumeration:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in newArray) {
    for (NSString *key in dict) {
        NSLog(@"%@=%@",key,[dict objectForKey:key]);
    }
}
```

Using an enumeration block:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in newArray) {
    [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"%@=%@",key, obj);
    }];
}
```

These produce the same results as the answer by @Rajeev.